# Javascript- Multi-level Drop Down Div Positioning?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm trying to to make a horizontal menu with CSS and JavaScript that is multi-level. I have a toggle function that shows the div container of the submenu, however, when it displays it pushes the links below the container. How can I make it so when I click the link to show a div container that it appears below the rest of the links. Also I would like to make it where only one link can be selected and I have no clue how to do it. I've never used JavaScript before and I'm fairly new to CSS.

I've removed almost all styling from my code. but here is the functionality.

```
    #togglebox {
                display:none;

                }

    #togglebox li{
            display: inline-block;
              }
    #extrabox {
                display:none;
                background: #E6ECF2;
                text-align: center;
                min-width: 100%;
                }

    #extrabox li{
            display: inline-block;
                }
    #extrabox2 {
                display:none;
                background: #E6ECF2;
                text-align: center;
                min-width: 100%;
                }
    #extrabox2 li{
            display: inline-block;
                }

function toggle_visibility(id) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   if(e.style.display == 'block')
      e.style.display = 'none';
   else
      e.style.display = 'block';
}

    <ul class="sub-menu" style="display:inline;">
    <a href="#"><li id="NSM1">Normal Sub Menu</li></a></td>
    <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('togglebox');"><li id="SMEL">Sub-menu Item with Second Level</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li id="NSM2">Normal Sub Menu</li></a>  
    <br />          
        </ul>
            <div id="togglebox">
                        <a  href="#"><li id="NSSL1">[Normal Link]</li></a>
                        <a  href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('extrabox');"><li id="SSL2">[Has extra Level]</li></a>
                        <div id="extrabox">
                            <a  href="#"><li id="sublinkea">3rd level item1</li></a>                    <a  href="#"><li id="sublinkeb">3rd level item2</li></a>                    <a  href="#"><li id="sublinkea">3rd level item3</li></a>
                            <a  href="#"><li id="sublinkeb">3rd level item4</li></a>                    
                    </div>
                    <a  href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('extrabox2');"><li id="SSL3"><li id="sublinksc">[Has Extra Level]</li></a>
                                                    <div id="extrabox2">
                                                                <a  href="#"><li id="sublinkea">3rd level item1</li></a>
                                                                <a  href="#"><li id="sublinkeb">3rd level item2</li></a>
                                                                <a  href="#"><li id="sublinkea">3rd level item3</li></a>
                                                                <a  href="#"><li id="sublinkeb">3rd level item4</li></a>                    
                                                    </div>
                      <a  href="#"><li id="NSSL2">[Normal Link]</li></a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like the trouble is that you have `#extrabox` as a child of `#togglebox`, when you really want it to a sibling. As it is, `#extrabox` will affect the positioning of any block-level elements that come after it (as siblings) under `#togglebox`. A quick fix looks like:

```
<div id="togglebox">
  <ul>
    <li id="NSSL1">
      <a  href="#">[Normal Link]</a>
    </li>
    <li id="SSL2">
      <a  href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('extrabox');">
        [Has extra Level]
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="extrabox">
  <!-- put #extrabox contents here -->
</div>
```

(I also went ahead and fixed the `a` tags that were children of `ul`; `ul` only takes `li` tags as children.)

Similarly, you'll want to move `#extrabox2` out from under `#extrabox` so that it doesn't affect the positioning of its siblings there.

I'm not sure what you mean by, "Also I would like to make it where only one link can be selected." Could you clarify that?

Hope that helps!

Comment: That helped!! thank you so much! I also have another question. Is there a way I could use that save div container to load different ul's? I was loading different div containers for each ul, but they will just pop up below each other and I would like for it to act as a sub menu so that each click loads a div of more lists in the same area.

Comment: Thats what i meant by selected. I realize now my wording was a little confusing, sorry about that!

Comment: Yep, you can do that. A quick and dirty (but not really maintainable) approach would involve changing the `innerHTML` property of the `div`. 

A better approach would create the new elements (maybe using [a template](http://underscorejs.org/#template) of some sort -- but that's not necessary for small use cases (and there are better options that Underscore templates, but each has its own learning curve)) and append them to the DOM tree at the place where you want to render them.

Comment: I would like to achieve the most proper way of going about this. I found this fiddle, but was unable to make it work when I place it within a document to edit it. http://jsfiddle.net/HpCWW/1/